# New to C and C Structures -- How to take a struct as a parameter in a function

Tags: c, function, parameters, struct

New to StackOverflow and new to C. I'm trying to take a struct as a parameter in a function 'add_fields', which adds the first two int fields 'a' and 'b' and puts the result in int field 'c'. Not getting anything from the compiler, so obviously I'm doing something wrong. I just don't know what. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    struct add{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    }

    void add_fields(struct add *d){
    d->c = a + b;

    }

    main(){

    struct add data;
    data.a = 1;
    data.b = 2;
    data.c = 0;
    add_fields(data);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", data.a, data.b, data.c);
}
```

Comment: "Not getting anything from the compiler, so obviously I'm doing something wrong."  What does this mean?  Does the compiler not issue an error?  Are your compiler's error and warning messages fully enabled?

Comment: About the compiler warnings, if you are using gcc, try the -Wall option. I assume this should be ANSI C as well, in which case you should use -ansi and make main() of type int.

Comment: When I said I didn't get anything from the compiler, I meant that I had errors. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: When your question concerns an error message, you should post the error too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're very close, but variables `a` and `b` don't exist in that context, rather you need to access the fields via the pointer to struct `d`:

```
d->c = d->a + d->b;
```

Second, you need to pass a reference to the struct (since `add_fields` expects a pointer) when you call `add_fields`:

```
add_fields(&data);
```

The `&` indicates that you're going to pass the address of the variable `data` rather than the value.

Comment: Also, a reference to `data` needs to be passed to `add_fields`, and not `data` itself.  And the `struct` block needs to end with a semicolon.

Comment: I am pleasantly surprised at how quick I got a helpful answer. Thank you very much. I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct add{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void add_fields(struct add *d){
    d->c = d->a + d->b;
}

int main(){

    struct add data;
    data.a = 1;
    data.b = 2;
    data.c = 0;
    add_fields(&data);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", data.a, data.b, data.c);

    return 0;
}
```

- You forgot a semicolon after the `struct` definition.
- I had to fix your `add_fields` function. You didn't use your `struct` for `a` and `b`.
- You needed to pass a pointer into `add_fields` (hence the `&`) in the function call. By passing a pointer in, your changes in `add_fields` were reflected on the outside calling `struct`.
- `main` always returns an `int`.

Comment: You are immensely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

In `main`, `data` is of type `struct add`.  When you call `add_field`, you need to pass it a `struct add*` (that is, a pointer to a `struct add`).  To get a pointer to `data` in `main`, you need to use the `&` operator:

```
add_fields(&data);
```

In `add_fields`, you need to use the "member access syntax" (the `->`) to access `a` and `b`.

Two other minor issues:  `main` should have a return type of `int`:

```
int main() { ...
```

and you need to place a semicolon after the closing `}` of a struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

C is call by value language. When you pass data, you are passing a copy of the object of type struct add. In your add_fields field, you are accepting a pointer to the struct. Since you want to change the fields of the struct, you should pass the address of the data struct (and accept a pointer to it in add_fields). To do this,

add_fields(&data);

Also, in add_fields, you aren't have undefined variables (a and b). I assume they should be from the struct, as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the memory address of the struct to the add_fields function.

```
add_fields(&data)
```

** Wow I was really slow on this one :P